# Trigger Greensock animation if body hasClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gsap

I have a class of `.header-is-active` that is applied to the `<body>` tag when a user scrolls.

I would like an animation to be triggered when the class is added and then the animation to run in reverse when the class is removed.

Everything happens as expected except for the animation. I'm using jQuery and Greensock to make everything happen.

Here's what I currently have:

```
$(function() {

    var body = $('body');
    var trigger = $('.trigger');
    var tween = TweenMax.to(trigger, 0.5, {css:{height: "100vh"},});

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 50) {
            body.addClass('header-is-active');
            tween();
        } else {
            body.removeClass('header-is-active');
        }
    });
});
```

The issue I have is the tweened value `height: 100vh` is being applied regardless with `.header-is-active` or not. Is there something missing?

Comment: Can you not just define the `tween` variable inside the `if` conditional?

Comment: @ObsidianAge As simple as that. Been staring at it for over an hour. One of those days. Thanks.

Comment: Haha no problem; I wasn't sure that doing that would solve your problem, but I'm glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your `$(window).scroll()` function, give this a shot:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 50) {
        body.addClass('header-is-active');
        tween();
    } else {
        body.removeClass('header-is-active');
    }

    // jQuery way
    if(body.hasClass('header-is-active')) {
        // Run animation
    } else {
        // Run reverse animation
    }

    // Non-jQuery way (just for reference)
    var body = document.body;
    if(body.classList.contains('header-is-active') {
        // Run animation
    } else {
        // Run reverse animation
    }

});
```

If it doesn't work, since it's running async, you can add a `setTimeout()` to the above so it's called after your function. It should look something like this

```
setTimeout(function() {
    if(body.hasClass('header-is-active')) {
        // run animation
    } else {
        // run reverse
    }
}, 0);
```